# object oriented factorial calculator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm new to python and I'm learning the basics of oo programming. I wanted to make a factorial calculator by creating a class. This is my code so far:

```
class Factorial:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def factorial(self):
        n = 1
        while number >= 1:
            n = n * number
            number = number - 1
        return n

num1 = Factorial(10)
print(num1.factorial())
```

But when I try this I receive the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fact.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(num1.factorial())
  File "fact.py", line 7, in factorial
    while number >= 1:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'number' referenced before assignment
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't understand how to assign number locally. I had the exact same problem yesterday when trying to write a program to verify if a number is prime. Can someone wxplain to me what I've failed to understand? I tried writing my code in a non-oo way and it worked fine.

```
number = 10
n = 1
while number >= 1:
    n = n * number
    number = number - 1

print(n)
```

Comment: Is there any reason to do things this way rather than writing an ordinary function? The point of object oriented programming isn't to take a simple task and make it needlessly more complicated. Also, if you try to calculate the factorial twice, you'll always get `1` the second time.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand the concept behind it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

use `self.number` in the class method factorial, instead of `number`